# How do I prevent getting large values when calculating denominator when using linspace?

Tags: numpy, python-fractions

```
x = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
for k in x:
    print (Fraction(k).denominator)
```

I 'm trying to get the denominator for this values in this range, but I get this instead

```
1
9007199254740992
4503599627370496
9007199254740992
2251799813685248
2251799813685248
4503599627370496
562949953421312
1125899906842624
1
```

Comment: Those are in fact the actual denominators of the actual numbers in your array, because floats can only represent rational numbers with power-of-two denominators. If you're doing something where the concept of a denominator is meaningful, you probably shouldn't be using floating-point math in the first place - you should use integer or rational math the whole way.

Comment: inclusive of end points you probably want 11 elements..  Loonk at `x` itself.

Comment: Where are you importing `Fraction` from?